# How to show up the div height?

Tags: html, height

Css:

```
   #container
     {
     position:relative;
     left: 27%;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
     }
```

Html:

```
   <div id="container">
 <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner.png" border=0></div>
 <div id="text"><p>Text</p></div>
     </div>
```

Depends on text size, the height of #container is increased...because of that i cant move the text to the bottom,i dont know why but #container acts like a wrapper in the true means of the word,is there any other way to change that?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? text at the bottom?

Comment: No.You see that i write there background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);,well i did it because i want it to be as a background for the contents,but it doesnt show up if  the div#container is empty,and when i insert something like a text for example,the container size is the same as the text size.I want it to be 100% height and to show up.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about m8

Comment: try making sure that the padding and margin values are set to 0. I'd suggest using a CSS reset such as this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrestled with div positioning over the last few months, and it's still frustrating.

I've made this:

CSS

```
#container {
     position:relative;
     left: 27%;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color:red;
}

#banner {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

#text {
    font-size:24px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="banner">picture</div>
<div id="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

And it gives me the "picture" on the top, and the text right below the picture.

Is that what you're looking for?